# Annotation missing when reading from external class in JAR executable

Tags: java

I wrote a program to read annotations from an external class and print out their names:

```
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Field field : Car.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
      for (Annotation a : field.getAnnotations()) {
        System.out.println(a.toString());
      }
      for (Annotation d : field.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
        System.out.println(d.toString());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```
public class Car {
  @Id
  private Integer carId;

  @NotNull
  private String carName;
}
```

Everything works fine when debugging, but when I compile and run it as JAR executable, the annotations are not found. How can I get the annotations when running the program as JAR file?

So I compiled my application as a JAR file. To run this file I use the following:

```
<output_path> $ java -jar <application-name>.jar
```

and I put my Car class (compiled as class) in:

```
<output_path>/code/com/example/base/myapp/classes/Car.class
```

Comment: `for (Field field : Car.class)`?

Comment: Are you sure that the annotations are on the classpath when you run your jar?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `RetentionPolicy` for the annotation. If it is `SOURCE` or `CLASS` you shouldn't expect to see them at runtime. Only `RUNTIME` annotations will be able to be read reflectively at runtime.

You also need to make sure that the annotation classes are on the classpath at runtime.

Here's an example:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AnnotationExample {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @interface SourceAnnotation {
    }
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @interface ClassAnnotation {
    }
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @interface RuntimeAnnotation {
    }

    @SourceAnnotation
    @ClassAnnotation
    @RuntimeAnnotation
    int foo;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Field field : AnnotationExample.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            for (Annotation a : field.getAnnotations()) {
                System.out.println(a.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

let's compile this and look at the class files:

```
$ javac AnnotationExample.java
$ ls *.class
AnnotationExample$ClassAnnotation.class     AnnotationExample$SourceAnnotation.class
AnnotationExample$RuntimeAnnotation.class
AnnotationExample.class
```

If we run it:

```
$ java -cp . AnnotationExample
@AnnotationExample$RuntimeAnnotation()
```

Now we delete the class file for the annotation:

```
$ rm AnnotationExample\$RuntimeAnnotation.class
$ java -cp . AnnotationExample
$
```

No error, but the annotation is not found.

Comment: All of my annotations have RUNTIME retention.... yet I still cannot see them

Comment: Please provide a complete program which reproduces your problem.

Comment: I compiled my application as a JAR file. To run this file I use the following:
`<output_path> $ java -jar <application-name>.jar`

and I put my Car class (compiled as class) in:
`<output_path>/code/com/example/base/myapp/classes/Car.class`. Optionally I can run with arguments: `com.example.base.myapp.classes.Car`

Comment: Java is not going to see your Car class there when you use the -jar option. Also, are the annotations in your jar file?

Comment: I'm not sure if the annotations can be seen in the Car class file. It seems like I cannot get my class annotations even if I read external class file. And I have no choice but to run -jar.

Comment: The annotation classes themselves need to be present on the classpath.